# Laravel is giving me Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Undefined variable: GENERAL_SETTING

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

This is my controller code to show data from GENERAL_SETTING table

```
    public function show()
    {
        // mengambil data dari table GENERAL_SETTING
        $GENERAL_SETTING = GeneralSettingModel::all();

        // mengirim data GENERAL_SETTING ke view /home
        return view('/home',['GENERAL_SETTING' => $GENERAL_SETTING]);
    }
```

This is the code in my view (home.blade.php)

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        @foreach($GENERAL_SETTING as $gs)
        <thead class="bg-primary">
            <tr class="border-1">
                <th scope="col" colspan="2" class="border-1">Hardware</th>
                <th scope="col" colspan="2" class="border-1">Communication</th>
                <th scope="col" class="border-1">Master Clock</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" >IP: {{ $gs->IP_HW }}</td>
                <td colspan="2" >SNMP Driver
                    <br>
                        Status: Connected
                    </br>
                </td>
                <td rowspan="4">IP: IP: {{ $gs->IP_MC }}
                    <br>
                        Status: Connecteds
                    </br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" >Temperature: 31</td>
                <td colspan="2" >Cloud Driver
                    <br>
                        URL: <a href="cloud.mqtt.com" target="_blank"> cloud.mqtt.com </a>
                    </br>
                    <br>
                        Status: Connected
                    </br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="bg-primary">Main</td>
                <td class="bg-primary">Backup</td>
                <td class="bg-primary">Master Driver</td>
                <td class="bg-primary">Slave Driver</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>IP: {{ $gs->IP_SERVER1 }}
                    <br>
                        Status: Connected
                    </br>
                </td>
                <td>IP: {{ $gs->IP_SERVER2 }}
                    <br>
                        Status: Connected
                    </br>
                </td>
                <td>IP: 192.168.1.15
                    <br>
                        Status: Connected
                    </br>
                </td>
                <td>IP: 192.168.1.16
                    <br>
                        Status: Connected
                    </br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        @endforeach
    </table>
</div>
```

And this is my routes (web.php)

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'FEPController@home');
Route::get('/home','GeneralSettingController@show');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

I try that code in other file (ex: dashboard.blade.php), that code can run normally. But, if I using home.blade.php, that error always show. What should I do to fix that error? Thank u.

Comment: does your table have data

Comment: Never ever give a name of variable as capital `$GENERAL_SETTING` should be small.

Comment: You have same route (home 3 times) returning different view. Change your routes e.g home/settings etc

Comment: @NipunTharuksha GENERAL_SETTING table has data.

Comment: @Laravel it doesn't work when I change that to lowercase

Comment: @SalmanZafar oh I see. But, my file is home.blade.php, can I change the route to /home/xx?

Comment: Yes you can change route to any thing e.g home/xx or home/abc etc

Comment: @SalmanZafar oke thank u. But, after login, it will be route to /home not /home/xx. But, if the route after login (
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');), the error always show.

Comment: if you want to share the same data between multiple views or without creating extra route you can use `View::share()` you can read here https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Comment: show your model too please

Comment: The problem was solved using @SalmanZafar solution. Thank u for your help, guys.

Answer (score -1):

In your `view()` just remove the forward slash in `/home` and it should look like this

```
 return view('home',['GENERAL_SETTING' => $GENERAL_SETTING]);.
```

Just a piece of advice, your code is very poor and you should do it like this

Controller

```
public function show()
{
    // mengambil data dari table GENERAL_SETTING
    $generalSettings  = GeneralSetting::all();

    // mengirim data GENERAL_SETTING ke view /home
    return view('/home',['generalSettings' => $generalSettings]);
}
```

Blade

```
 @foreach($generalSettings as $gs)
   //
 @endforeach
```

More details

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank u for your help. But it doesn't work. The problem is in this code:
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

That code is route after login. If there is that code, error still show.

Comment: The possible reason for this is that you didn't point the correct view. So try to post your blade path here starts from resources/....

Comment: also if your route is HomeController@index like this, you shoud change that to HomeController@show in order to point the correct method.

Comment: This is my HomeController code
`<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
`

Comment: Paste here the path of your blade